# I cannot disable a control with ng-disabled

Tags: angular

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="func()">{{Hello}}</button>
      <button ng-disabled="press" (click)="func2()">Click</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  Hello: string = "Hello";
  press: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  func() {
    this.Hello="Blah";
    this.press = true;
  }

  func2() {
    alert("Here");
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have created a very simple form, and pasted it from Plunker. This is the app.ts from a newly created 'Angular' project.

This is the code. I expect that after I press the first button, the second one will be disabled. However, i can always get the alert to pop-up.

I have attached some plunker code, that doesn't work. Any help gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Use `[disabled]` instead of `ng-disabled` with `Angular2+`

```
<button [disabled]="press" (click)="func2()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to extend this to use with an <input> tag. Since your advice i am now using [readonly]="variable".